# Importing an svg file doesn't work

Tags: import, image

I have bender version 2.76. I know this question has already been asked, I have have read the threads, but I still have the same problem. I have an svg file of a manta and I can't import it into Blender.

I understand an svg file off the net is not necessarily an svg blender can read. So I took my file, put it through inkscape, path- trace bitmap, saved it, and then imported the svg into Blender. But I don't see my image. I have tried scrolling in and out of the blender file to see if my image was on a smaller scale or something. but it still isn't there.

Comment: You mentioned tracing a bitmap, I believe blender can only import vector data from SVG files, not bitmap images.in fact raster data in SVG files is frequently pointless or unwanted. Can you post a link to the SVG file in questio? It is frequently of a very small or very large scale and you have to zoom selected to see it, try checking the outliner if there are any new curve object's after import.

Comment: If it has imported any vectors try hitting the period on the numpad. It may be scaled up really big or really small. If it is really big, then you should be able to scale it down 0.1 at a time until you see it. Assuming its there at all. Or instead of scaling you could adjust your view clip to be 10000. Worth a shot.

Comment: If you are able to share the .svg file, that might help us understand what the problem is and work around it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import svg files](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48878/import-svg-files)